# type mismatch and other few errors unable to resolve them

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class sample
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);    //taking input from user
long t=in.nextLong();
long a[]=new long[1000];            //array of long numbers
for(long i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
    a[i]=in.nextLong();          //values into array
   }
sort(a,t);
return 0;
}
void sort(long a[],long t)
 { 
 long count=0,temp;
 for(long i=0;i<t;i++)
 {
  for(long j=i+1;j<t;j++)            //sorting the array using selection sort
   {
        if(a[i]<a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[j]=a[i];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
    }
}
for(long j=0;j<t;j++)
{
   if(a[t]-3*a[j+1]<=0)
continue;               
else                                     //program for chang and mathematical champ
count++;
 }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

$
        1)type mismatch error 
        2)Void methods cannot return a value
        3) Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sort(long[], long) from    the type 
        How to solve these

Comment: First problem: You seem to think that `$` is used for comments. It's `//` or `/* ... */` instead.

Comment: The other problems are fairly basic too - what do you think it means to return a value from a `void` method? As for "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" - just search here...

Comment: i didn't use return in void sort function right

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean that in your *real* code you don't use `$` for comments, how would you expect us to know that? And what research have you performed for the other errors? Additionally, it would really help if you'd pay more attention to formatting your code cleanly when posting.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code and replace `$` with `//` if those are comments. It's much harder for people to understand your code and thus help you if it looks so messy.

Comment: @user3427895: The return statement is in the `main` method - which should be clear to you if you pay attention to the line number in the error message.

Comment: i am new to this site but sorry....

Comment: got it and for type mismatch cannot convert long to int

Comment: unable to fix the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The line `for(long i=0;i<a.length;i++)` and similar, where `i` is used to index an array, should be `for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)` because arrays (and lists) are indexed by integers, not longs;
2. You are returning 0 at line 14. If you want to exit with a value you need to call `System.exit(0);` although it's not good practice. Or you can just call return;
3. You could declare `sort` static as in `static void sort(...)`.

As a side note, you clearly are a beginner in java. I highly recommend reading "Effective Java 2nd Ed" by Joshua Bloch to understand how java works. Or at least go off the [java trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial) to learn how java works. You **will** get burned if you don't study.

Comment: could you send better link as the above link doesn't contain complete info on java

Comment: unable to fix the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

Comment: Changed the link. It mentions Java 8 but most of the tutorials apply to 7 and below as well. They will tell you which features are 8 specific I believe.